# Change domain1 to domain2 without refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

May I know is there anyway can change the domain www.domain1.com to www.domain2.com without refresh the page?

Example like

Will change to new domain without refresh the page

Comment: Nope. Thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

I think we cannot do this. Please check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy